# Testing login scaffolding in Laravel with PHPunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Can't make this pass the login test with Laravel scaffolding.

I tried accessing database `$user` with `$user = User::first();` and also using factory `User::factory()->create();`. In both cases I'm able to successfully `dd($user)` info, so it means `$user` exists and can be accessed.

I also tried hardcoding credentials with `bcrpyt()` and `Hash::make` password - where the error also appears to happen.

I'm not ussing `RefreshDatabase` trait.

```
public function test_log_user()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    // $user = User::first();
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    // dd($user);

    $response = $this->post('/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => $user->password, //line 47
    ]);

    $response->getStatusCode();
    // $response->dumpHeaders();
    // $response->dump();
    $response->assertStatus(302);
}
```

Getting this error:

> Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\react\React-Laravel\vinos-gdl\tests\Feature\AuthTest.php:47

I have already cleared cache, routes, config.

phpunit.xml:

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
<server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
<server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
<server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

I also have a `test_create_user` which passes correctly

```
public function test_create_user()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $user = [
        'name' => Factory::create()->name(),
        'email' => Factory::create()->email(),
    ];

    $response = $this->post('/register', [
        'name' => $user['name'],
        'email' => $user['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
        'password_confirmation' => Hash::make('123456')
    ]);

    // $response->dumpHeaders();
    // $response->dump();

    $response->assertStatus(302);
}
```

Comment: You want to pass the plaintext password to your form and not `$user->password` which will be a hash.

Comment: Hey the very first test (not the register test) uses `$user->password`. I tried using `Hash` and `bcrypt` in that one with no luck. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You don't want to hash the password in the first test, you want to use the plaintext password. Laravel will hash the plaintext and compare it to the hash in the database. You're hashing a hash before comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test_log_user()` function is using the already hashed password for your `user` as the form password which, is then being hashed again before being checked against the value in the database.

The `user` `factory` sets the password field for a user to be a hash of the word `password` (unless you have changed this). For example:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->name,
        'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
}
```

So in your `test_log_user()` function:

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
```

Creates a new `user` in the database with `$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi` as the value in the password field (a hash of the word `password`).

So the value of `$user->password` is not `password`, it is `$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi`.

What you want to do is pass the plaintext password through:

```
$response = $this->post('/login', [
    'email' => $user->email,
    'password' => 'password' 
]);
```

Comment: That was it. Many thanks for clearing my path up!